# How can I include properly javascript files in my wp plugin

Tags: plugins, javascript

I am creating a plugin for wordpress. And I want to know how can I include properly js in my plugin with correct path function. 
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? We have hundreds of posts about that. Please use our search.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can use 
    plugin_dir_url(**FILE**)
function to get the path of your js file. And enqueue script like this:-

```
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','ir_jscripts');
   function ir_jscripts()
   {
       wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript',plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'/jquery/script.js', array(), '3.3.5', true );

   }
```

Thanks